# Select distinct value using STRING_AGG

Tags: sql-server

I want to select distinct customer so i wrote this query:

```
SELECT 
   STRING_AGG( ISNULL(Concat(Year(info.[CreationDate]),'/',Trim('BS-' from info.ProjectN)) , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllProjectN'
  ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL(part.Designation , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllDesignation' 
  ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL([GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[Quantity] , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllQuantity'
  ,[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]

  ,(SELECT STRING_AGG( ISNULL(cust.Name , ' '), ' ;')
   WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust.Name)
   FROM (SELECT distinct cust.Name FROM Customer)as x) AS AllCustomer

  FROM [dbo].[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle]
  Inner Join GalvaQualityDailyProduction prod on prod.id= 
  [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].FK_idDailyProduction
  Inner join GalvaParts part on part.id=prod.[FK_idPart]
  Inner join ProjectInfoGalva info on info.id=part.IdProject
  inner Join Customer cust on cust.ID=info.FK_Customer
  Group By cust.Name,[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
```

But when I run it I get duplicate customer 
[image]

How can I get just a distinct customer?

Comment: Did you actually mean to select `cust.Name`, which is from the outer `inner Join Customer cust`, as opposed to the inner unaliased `FROM Customer`?

Comment: Your query is confusing and not conveying fully what you have and want. Edit the question and provide a [example]. I.e. first simplify the problem, then provide the CREATE TABLE statements and INSERT INTO statements the problem can reproduced with. Add the desired result as tabular text you wish to generate from the given sample data

Comment: @Bouabdallah; Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1:

```
SELECT 
    STRING_AGG( ISNULL(Concat(Year(info.[CreationDate]),'/',Trim('BS-' from info.ProjectN)) , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllProjectN'
    ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL(part.Designation , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllDesignation' 
    ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL([GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[Quantity] , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllQuantity'
    ,[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
    ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL(cust.Name , ' '), ' ;') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust.Name) AS AllCustomer
FROM [dbo].[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle]
Inner Join GalvaQualityDailyProduction prod on prod.id = [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].FK_idDailyProduction
Inner join GalvaParts part on part.id=prod.[FK_idPart]
Inner join ProjectInfoGalva info on info.id=part.IdProject
inner Join Customer cust on cust.ID=info.FK_Customer
Group By [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
```

Answer 2 :

```
With CustomersName as (
    SELECT
        [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
        ,STRING_AGG(ISNULL(cust.[Name] , ' '), ' ;') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY cust.[Name]) as AllCustomer

    FROM [dbo].[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle]
    Inner Join GalvaQualityDailyProduction prod on prod.id = [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].FK_idDailyProduction
    Inner join GalvaParts part on part.id=prod.[FK_idPart]
    Inner join ProjectInfoGalva info on info.id=part.IdProject
    inner Join Customer cust on cust.ID=info.FK_Customer
    Group By [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
)
SELECT 
   STRING_AGG( ISNULL(Concat(Year(info.[CreationDate]),'/',Trim('BS-' from info.ProjectN)) , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllProjectN'
  ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL(part.Designation , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllDesignation' 
  ,STRING_AGG( ISNULL([GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[Quantity] , ' '), ' ;')  As 'AllQuantity'
  ,[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
  ,CustomersName.AllCustomer
FROM [dbo].[GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle]
Inner Join GalvaQualityDailyProduction prod on prod.id = [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].FK_idDailyProduction
Inner join GalvaParts part on part.id=prod.[FK_idPart]
Inner join ProjectInfoGalva info on info.id=part.IdProject
inner Join CustomersName on CustomersName.ID=info.FK_Customer
Group By CustomersName.AllCustomer, [GalvaQualityDailyFicheControle].[CreationDate]
```